# Pop up alert vb 6

Tags: vb6

Can someone help me. I'm having a hard time with this. All I need is to display an alert message whenever the medicines expired.My problem is when I got two or more expired medicines it doesn't alert all.Instead it alerts one medicine.Please help.

here is my code

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next

    With Main
        .Text4 = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("MedicineName")
        .Text1.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("genericname")
        .Text3.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("StockQuantity")
        .Combo3 = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expmonth")
        .Combo4 = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expday")
        .Combo5 = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expyear")
    End With

    Dim expirationdate As Date
    expirationdate = CDate(Combo3 & "/" & Combo4 & "/" & Combo5)
    datepicker.Value = Format(Now, "MMM-DD-yyyy")
    If datepicker > expirationdate Then
        MsgBox Text4.Text & " is expired ", vbExclamation, "Warning!"
        If MsgBox("Do you want to dispose " & Text4 & "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Message") = vbYes Then
            Adodc1.Recordset.Delete
        ElseIf vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Adodc1.CommandType = adCmdUnknown
    Adodc1.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\clinic.mdb" & ";Persist Security Info=False"
    Adodc1.RecordSource = "select * from inventory order by Expyear asc"
    Adodc1.Refresh
    Adodc1.Refresh
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bond is correct, you need to iterate over your recordset to display the message for each record that is expired.

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Dim expirationdate As Date

    On Error Resume Next    '<-- this is going to cause a problem if you never check for errors

    Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst    'make sure the control is positioned on the first record
    Do While Adodc1.Recordset.EOF = False    'loop over all of the records
        With Main
            .Text4.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("MedicineName")
            .Text1.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("genericname")
            .Text3.Text = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("StockQuantity")
            .Combo3 = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expmonth")
            .Combo4 = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expday")
            .Combo5 = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expyear")
        End With

        expirationdate = CDate(Combo3 & "/" & Combo4 & "/" & Combo5)
        datepicker.Value = Format(Now, "MMM-DD-yyyy")
        If datepicker > expirationdate Then
            MsgBox Text4.Text & " is expired ", vbExclamation, "Warning!"
            If MsgBox("Do you want to dispose " & Text4 & "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Message") = vbYes Then
                Adodc1.Recordset.Delete
            End If
        End If
        Adodc1.Recordset.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Sir but how can display two or more expired medicine at the same time?.I've got a problem with Text4 it just assigning one value.

Comment: Please see the changes I made to the code. It will continue to loop until all the records have been processed.

Comment: It works now sir thanks :)
But I still have problems when I tried to display the value of expired medicines of different table. It gives me an error.
Could you please take a look at my second post Sir. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all of the records in your recordset. Currently, you're operating on the FIRST record only.

```
Do Until Adodc1.Recordset.EOF

    ' Assign values to textboxes, test date, etc.

    ' Fetch the next record...    
    Adodc1.Recordset.MoveNext

Loop
```

Comment: Here what i've done Sir.I have still the same problem. Seems my codes is wrong.I don't know how to loop it.I'm not really good in vb. 

'Do Until Adodc1.Recordset.EOF

    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("MedicineName") = Text4.Text
     Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("genericname") = Text1.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("StockQuantity") = Text3.Text
   Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expmonth") = Combo3.Text
   Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expday") = Combo4.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Expyear") = Combo5.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.MoveNext
Loop'

Comment: It looks like you're assigning TO the recordset instead of FROM it like in your original post. Don't you want `Text4.Text = Adodc1.Recordset("MedicineName")` instead? That will copy the value from the recordset to your textbox. Then, add your date-checking code within this loop and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've got a problem Sir with text4 it just assigning one value.
All I need is to display all the expired medicines at the same time without getting the value of recordset in text4.
How to do that Sir?

Comment: Maybe you should add a listbox to your form and add each expired medicine to the listbox? You'll need some way to display multiple medicines. A listbox would work better than a message box.

Comment: Can you give me an example Sir? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `If datepicker > expirationdate Then List1.AddItem Adodc1.Recordset("MedicineName")`